# UITextField in UITableViewCell becomeFirstResponder after insertion

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield, becomefirstresponder

As the title states, I have a `UITextField` inside a `UITableViewCell`.

My tableView lists items in an array called `tallies: [String]`

I'm inserting a new entry on button tap, and animating in the new cell. I want the `titleTextField` to `becomeFirstResponder` once the `rowAnimation` has completed, but so far cannot get it to work.

The new row animates in perfectly, but the `titleTextField` won't `becomeFirstResponder`

Here's what I've tried:

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
    let cell = self.tableView(self.tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: self.editingIndexPath!) as! TallyCell
    cell.titleTextField.hidden = false
    cell.titleTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
}

tableView.beginUpdates()
tallies.append("Example")
tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([editingIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Left)
tableView.endUpdates()

CATransaction.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Make textField first responder after row insertion.

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated that it seems to stop the row animation if I call it directly after

Comment: Remove CTTransaction and do something like  [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
    [cell.textLabel becomeFirstResponder];

Comment: Tried that too. no luck

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
    let cell = self.tableView(self.tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: self.editingIndexPath!) as! TallyCell
    cell.titleTextField.hidden = false
}

tableView.beginUpdates()
tallies.append("Example")
tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([editingIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Left)
tableView.endUpdates()
CATransaction.commit()
let cellNew = self.tableView(self.tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.editingIndexPath!) as! TallyCell
cellNew.titleTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Comment: That won't work, as `cell` is defined within the block

Comment: but you need to do it after CATransaction.commit()

Comment: check edited answer

Comment: No luck there. Simply ignores the becomeFirstResponder call